# Division of a figure with no symmetry into equal parts

Tags: plane-geometry, symmetry

> A circle or a rectangle can be easily cut into any number of parts
> that are equal by both shape and area. Is there a plane figure with the same
> property that has neither a center of symmetry nor a line of symmetry?
> The parts must be equal in both shape and area.

My thoughts are the following.
There are not too many figures with this property - some trapezoids (I was checking the right ones) and scalene triangles (I was checking the right ones too). No luck.
Then I got an idea that there can be some combination of a semicircle and a rectangle or a triangle. I checked these figures too - no luck.

Comment: You can also combine shapes with axis of symmetry, by drawing a line which connects the centers of symmetry of each individual shape (for example, a rectangle with a circular "hole").

Comment: @CarlosLopez: how would you dissect in *any number* of parts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A figure without bent lines inspired by [Woody3's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4353131/11206) first figure (and by my notebook).
[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is trivially achieved by "extruded" shapes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1, a figure without bent lines would be your first figure where your replace the left part by a parallelogram.

Comment: I don't understand. It is asymmetric.

Comment: this is what I meant https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5TdT.png

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand all of your comments because of my poor Englisch. But now I have got it.

Comment: @miracle173: never mind.